# How to save result mongoDB query to an array or list?

Tags: javascript

My query

```
test.find({ "age" : "20" }, {"email": 1, "_id": 0}).toArray(function (err,data) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log(data);
```

and result after I run my query

```
[ { email: 'root@root.com' } ]
```

How can I save `console.log(data);` to an Array or list ?
I tried `.push(data)` to save but not ok.

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty object and then assign value to it

```
test.find({ "age" : "20" }, {"email": 1, "_id": 0}).toArray(function (err,data) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(data);
var obj =[];
var obj = data;
```

Comment: Sorry, It's not work for me.
` ReferenceError: data is not defined `

Comment: Did you add it inside promise

Comment: var listEmail = [];  
     test.find({ "age" : "20" }, {"email": 1, "_id": 0}).toArray(function (err,data) {
              if (err) throw err;
              console.log(data);
        var obj ={};
        var obj = data;
       listEmail.push(data);

It's not work.

Comment: Don't use push check my answer

Comment: Sorry. Can you help me save it to list or array ?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried so many times with different ways but when I `Console.log(obj)` it only print `[ ]`